# "Object library invalid or contains references to object definitions that could not be found" comes up after some time

Tags: excel, vba

So I have this workbook with alot of sheets, three with form objects. Three buttons are form controls, just for navigation between the sheets, the others are ActiveX objects.

The form objects work just fine in the beginning but after a while they stop working, showing the error: "Object library invalid or contains references to object definitions that could not be found."

I can't even press the form controls. Which basically runs code like.

```
Sub Show_EBS_Sheet()
Worksheets("EBS").Activate
End Sub
```

No buttons, checkboxes, comboboxes works.

Nothing has really changed. I just open it, I interact with the form objects and then it doesn't work anymore. Have to restart Excel, then it works again. Anyone have an idea what might be causing this??

One button deletes some activeX checkboxes and creates new ones. Maybe that is the culprit?

This is the code that deletes the checkboxes:

```
Dim s As Shape
For Each s In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    If s.Type = 12 Then
        If Not Intersect(s.TopLeftCell, Sheets("EmpChoice").Range("A14:T33")) Is Nothing Then
            s.Delete
        End If
    End If
Next
```

I have tried to delete all .exd files but it didn't help. They reappeared once I started Excel again and the same problem happened again.

Comment: Are you unloading your forms correctly? You could be causing a bottleneck in your memory that is preventing it from loading correctly.

Comment: That might be it. I'll update the question with more code!

Comment: If you google that error the top suggestion for a fix is "Find and delete all files with .exd extension" - did you try that?

Comment: I did google and saw that but didn't try it. I'll try it!

Comment: Ok I deleted all .exd files. When I started up Excel again, they were created again. Couldn't get rid of them for good. The behavior continued. I was able to press the buttons and change the comboboxes but after some time they wouldn't work, showing the error. A restart helped, and I was able to use the form objects again. Then after some time they stopped working again.